# get name of option tag

Tags: javascript, html

i have dropdown in html and i have an  dictionary in back-end to get key.
since the dropdown is dynamically created so user keep adding to it.

```
<select id="cars">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Opel</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
```

now since there is no value attribute like

```
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
```

how i can get the name of option using onchange attribute
when user select

```
<option>Saab</option>
```

javascript should be able to get **Saab** and *insert it b/w h1 tag*

```
document.querySelector('#cars').onchange=function(){
            document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = //what to enter 
           // here to fetch get name of option currently selected.

           };

           <h1><h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `onchange` function, you can simply refer to the select box's value; by default, if there's no value attribute on the option, it'll default to using the option's text.

```js
document.querySelector('#cars').onchange = function() {
  document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = this.value;
};
```

```html
<select id="cars">
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Honda</option>
  <option>Volkswagen</option>
</select>

<h1 id="result"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need `this.value` as `this` refers to the select and when options have no specified value, their content becomes the value by default.

```js
document.querySelector('#cars').onchange = function() {
  document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = this.value
};
```

```html
<select id="cars">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Opel</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
<h1><h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector('#cars').onchange=function(){
    document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
};
```

```html
<select id="cars">
  <option>Volvo</option>
  <option>Saab</option>
  <option>Opel</option>
  <option>Audi</option>
</select>
<h1><h1>
```